# trouble listing directories that contain files with specific file extensions

Tags: unix, solaris

How to I list only directories that contain certain files. I am running on a Solaris box. Example, I want to list sub-directories of directory ABC that contain files that end with .out, .dat and .log .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines might work out for you:

```
find ABC/ \( -name "*.out" -o -name "*.log" \) -print | while read f
do
  echo "${f%/*}"
done | sort -u
```

The `sort -u` bit could be just `uniq` instead, but either should work.

Should work on `bash` or `ksh`. Probably not so much on `/bin/sh` - you'd have to replace the variable expansion with something like `echo "${f}" | sed -e 's;/[^/]*$;;'` or something else that would strip off the last component of the path. `dirname "${f}"` would be good for that, but I don't recall if Solaris includes that utility...

Comment: Thanks guys. I want to add to this question. After listing the files and reviewing them, is there a way with either one command or a script to delete them if needed? I know i can do an rm -R <directory name> for each directory but if there is a way to script it then I would prefer this method.I am talking about deleting the directories. I am running solaris 10 with a bash shell.... Thanks in advance.

Comment: If none of the paths have spaces or other shell-special characters in them, then adding `| xargs rm -r` to the end of the command should work. If there are things in the names that would cause the shell grief, then `| while read d; do rm -r "${d}"; done` would probably be better...